# What is the correct way to draw NFA of RE (a|b|c)?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

We were assigned to draw NFA for regular expression `a|b|c`, so like any one I draw this

[image: wrong way?]

But my professor told me it is wrong, the correct way is

[image: correct way?]

So, I checked it on online tools [toolbox by cyberzhg](https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/regex2nfa?regex=YXxifGM=), and [regexper](https://regexper.com/#a%7Cb%7Cc) and according to both of them I am also correct.

Professor's argument was in maths for `4+5+1`, we first add either `4+5` or `5+1` together then we add result of it with the remaining number. That is why for `a|b|c`, the correct solution is either `(a|b)|c` or `a|(b|c)`.

Can you please tell are we both correct?

Comment: Your professor might have said that you should use Thompson's algorithm, which, in it's simplest implementation, gives their answer and not yours. (Or it might give a different answer if `|' is considered to be right associative.)  But based on the professors explanation, it sounds like this is not the case.  I would like to see how the professor adds 43242 + 33543 + 34325 by hand.

Comment: Oh I just realised the professor did mention *Thompson's notation*

Comment: Maybe "Thompson's Construction" is the right term rather than Thompson's notation or algorithm.  Fun fact: this was invented by Ken Thompson while he was a master's student.  Did you ever wonder why regular expressions are so prevalent in Unix?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell No sir, I don't know! You tell me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no unique way of converting a regex into NFA. That is, for any regular language $L$ there exist multiple (even, infinite) number of NFAs that accept the language $L$.

The solution of your professor restricts each state to have at  most 2 outgoing states, while your solution does not. Unless this restriction was required by the professor somehow, both solutions are equivalent in the sense they both accept the language $L=\{a, b, c\}$ defined by the regexp `a|b|c`.

Note, that the professor might wanted you to work in methodological way, where there are fixed "gadgets", i.e., converting `x|y` to some certain states, and converting `xy` to other (fixed) states. Then, their comment makes sense - they wanted you to interpret `a|b|c` as `(a|b)|c`, first use the gadget on `a|b` to obtain the upper half of the machine, and then use the gadget again on `x|c` where $x$ is the already-constructed machine.
If this (or any fixed other) methodology was required, then  the outcome NFA would be unique.